# Duda con Ajax en Jquery y Controller en C# .net 6

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buen día.

Consulto ya que, al enviar parametros desde Ajax en mi front, los datos llegan como 0 o null en el controlador al que apunta el URL.

Quisiera saber que me estaría faltando para poder pasar el parametro correctamente.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Auth/Create',
        data: JSON.stringify({id:1}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
});
```

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    // POST: AuthController/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([FromBody] int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

dejaré capturas del debbugin para que se visualice mejor, estoy mandando id: 1 y llega 0 en el Controller (y del program.cs).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACIÓN.

Tampoco funciona enviando sin el JSON.stringify

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quitale el FromBody

Comment: Tampoco funciona, igual llega 0

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, pestaña network y mira cómo es el paquete que se está enviando.

Comment: Es porque tú url está mal, cambia `url: '../Auth/Create'` por `url: '/Auth/Create'`

Comment: @Daniel,  Si la url estuviese mal, estaría obteniendo un 404, no crees?

Comment: @Arriel gracias, no mire bien, tienes razon

Comment: Amigo [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054512/ajax-post-int-parameter-in-asp-net-core) la respuesta, me pasaba lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Si esto funciona, voy a expandir la respuesta, pero intenta agregar el signo + al id donde envías la data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Auth/Create',
    data: JSON.stringify({+id}), // agrega el signo + para obligar a que sea numérico
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

En el controlador mantén el `public ActionResult Create([FromBody] int id)`. Recomiendo utilizar `IActionResult`, en lugar de `ActionResult` como el retorno del método `Create`.

Creo que puedes, también, dejar el url como `'Auth/Create'` sin los puntos y la primera `'/'`. Me avisas si funciona

Answer (score 1):

intenta cambiando `ActionResult` por `IActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

y con ajax hazlo de esta manera

```
var data = {
    id: 1
};

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Auth/Create',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
});
```

aunque deberías especificar si estas enviando los datos con un button , entonces también deberías cambiar tu función en jquery, por un onclick

```
$('#submit').on('click',function () { .... }
```

Comment: No creo que el problema esté en el tipo de retorno, o en el evento click. OP dijo que su problema es que el id llega en 0 y no veo cómo esta respuesta lo resuelve

Comment: @Arriel entonces es mejor que comparta una replica en GitHub y así poder debuggear mejor y encontrar el error

Answer (score 0):

el principal problema es que estas enviando un string esperando recibir un int, en tu ajax tienes: `data: JSON.stringify({id:1}),` lo cual envia esto:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({id:1}))
console.log("El parametro que enviamos es de tipo: " + typeof(JSON.stringify({id:1})))
```

Para enviarlo correctamente sería sin `JSON.stringify` enviando el parametro de esta manera:

```js
console.log({id:1})
console.log("El parametro que enviamos es de tipo: " + typeof({id:1}))
```

Al ser un objeto entonces al llegar al controlador identificara el parámetro id y le asignará el valor correspondiente.

Comment: Buenas, envié de la forma que me indicas e igual ocurre el mismo error, subiré la actualización en la pregunta.

Comment: prueba de esta manera: `url: '../Auth/Create?id=1',` si así no te llega es que hay algo por ahí que no hemos visto

Comment: tampoco funciona, a menos que ponga método GET, pero necesito que sea por método POST

Comment: dices en el controlador???

Comment: En el $.ajax ... si coloco metodo GET y al final de url coloco ?id=1 si funciona, pero necesito que sea con metodo post en el ajax, no GET